# Laravel 8 Livewire CRUD Functions not working after deploying to localhost server

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-8

I'm a newbie when it comes to Laravel, I developed a CRUD App using Laravel 8 (TALL Stack). On my development machine, the modals, pagination, search and CRUD functions are working properly, but after deploying the app to a separate localhost server, the modals won't open, I can't create, edit or delete records, live search and pagination also not working. Please help me rectify this.

Comment: Please provide more details, "don't work" can have lots of reasons. Enable debug mode in .env and then add debug log in your question.

Comment: @AliPadida, thanks for the response, however the app's laravel log exceeds the maximum number of characters that can be accommodated along with the question

Comment: You're welcome. I understand, you can paste the log in https://pastebin.com/ and attach its link to the question.

Comment: Pastebin is failing to create the link. I think its timing out due to the size of the error log